# Using a bash script to apply another script to every file in a directory like a matrix

Tags: bash, shell, matrix, scripting, file-handling

Let's say in my directory I have five files.

Files: 1,2,3,4, & 5

I have a script that will do a mathematical process to compare two files and I want to use this script on every file in the directory, example below.

compare file 1 to 2,3,4, & 5

compare file 2 to 3,4, & 5

compare file 3 to 4 & 5

compare file 4 to 5

The files follow this name scheme filename_V0001.txt

How can a write a simple bash script to do this?

Comment: I would save the glob to an array, get its length, then loop on indices like you would do in any other programming language to avoid hacks like the one in Alfe's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**script_v1.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
compare="/path/to/my/compare_tool"

for i in {1..5}; do
    for j in $(seq $((i+1)) 5); do
        echo "Comparing $i and $j"
        compare filename_V000$i.txt filename_V000$j.txt > result_$i_$j.txt
    done
done
```

**result_v1:**

```
$ > bash script_v1.sh
Comparing 1 and 2
Comparing 1 and 3
Comparing 1 and 4
Comparing 1 and 5
Comparing 2 and 3
Comparing 2 and 4
Comparing 2 and 5
Comparing 3 and 4
Comparing 3 and 5
Comparing 4 and 5
$ >
```

**script_v2.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
compare="/path/to/my/compare_tool"

for i in {1..100}; do
    for j in $(seq $((i+1)) 100); do
        fi="Filename_V$(printf "%04d" $i).txt"
        fj="Filename_V$(printf "%04d" $j).txt"
        if [[ -f "$fi" && -f "$fj" ]]; then
            echo "Comparing $fi and $fj"
            compare "$fi" "$fj" > result_$i_$j.txt
        fi
    done
done
```

**result_v2:**

```
$ > bash script_v2.sh
Comparing Filename_V0001.txt and Filename_V0002.txt
...
Comparing Filename_V0001.txt and Filename_V0100.txt
Comparing Filename_V0002.txt and Filename_V0003.txt
...
Comparing Filename_V0002.txt and Filename_V0100.txt
Comparing Filename_V0003.txt and Filename_V0004.txt
...
Comparing Filename_V0099.txt and Filename_V0100.txt
$ >
```

> ASSUMPTIONS:
>
> - the scripts are called from the path the files reside in

Comment: I really like this method and it works great, thank you. How would I go about modifying it so it would work with numbers in the 100 range; so I can have it look through files labeled, Filename_V0001.txt to Filename_V0100.txt?

Comment: @Chemist not a Programmer: i've added one more example.

Comment: This makes perfect sense but when I try it on a directory with only 15 files I get an error at the numbers 0008 and 0009. I am not sure why?

Comment: Once I add the "V" in front of the numbers for Filename_V(ect...).txt it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in *
do
  start=0
  for b in *
  do
    if [ "$start" = 1 ]
    then
      echo "Comparing $a with $b ..."
      diff "$a" "$b"
    elif [ "$a" = "$b" ]
    then
      start=1
    fi
  done
done
```

Any name scheme for the files can of course be given in the glob pattern, e. g. `for a in filename_V*.txt`.

Comment: Right, @TomFenech.  Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

One fairly general way of doing it:

```
#!/bin/sh
for comp1; do
  shift
  for comp2; do
    echo "Comparing '$comp1' with '$comp2'"
    do_compare "$comp1" "$comp2"
  done
done
```

Then you can call that script with the list of files to compare:

```
do_all_compares Filename_V*.txt
```

`for x` is equivalent to `for x in "$@"`. The list is computed when the `for` statement is executed, so the `shift` which happens at the start of the loop will only affect the list for the inner comparisons.